# What is the meaning of "put any stock"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Cop whispering to the lady who is sitting beside Dr. Russell

> I'm here to do an interview with that Dr. Russell. I'm gonna expose her
>   as a fraud. You don't **put any stock** in this cold fusion mumbo jumbo?

Is it means investing the money?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means "not put any faith in", as in:

> You don't believe any of this cold fusion mumbo jumbo, do you?

It does stem from investing money, yes - as in don't invest your money in this, it's no good. However it applies now to generally not believing something.

Comment: See: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stock    for more background to the significance of *stock*.